# Some Kind of Generalized Brownian Bridge

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $\displaystyle X(t) = \int_0^t f(s)dB(s)$ where $B(t)$ is a Brownian motion and $f(t)\in L^2[0,1]$. What is a simple representation for $Y(t):=(X(t)|X(1))$ in terms of $B(t)$? Note, I am not asking for the (conditional) probability distribution of $Y(t)$

I am thinking of this as a generalization of the [Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge#cite_ref-1), which has several representation in terms of the Brownian motion $B(t)$.

Comment: A time-changed Brownian bridge?

Comment: @Hans : It is quite easy to derive the law $X$ bridge as $Xt$ is gaussian (Wiener integral). So you have the law of the couple $ (X_t,X_1)$ which is multivariate gaussian r.v.. Then you have well known theorems to derive the law of $X_t|X_1$ whcih is gaussian with modified expectation and variance (check wiki (section conditional distributions here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: I have no problem deriving the law of this $X$ bridge. It is a simple conditional probability. That is NOT my question. What I am after is the kind of expression the standard Brownian bridge has, such as $B(t)-tB(1)$. I am wondering if there is a similar expression for $Y(t)$ in terms of $B(t)$ just like the expression for the standard Brownian bridge.

Comment: @Hans : check this : https://math.aalto.fi/reports/a481.pdf

Comment: @TheBridge: Thank you. I actually also came across this paper yesterday which looks pertinent but have yet to check it out. Your reference adds the probability this paper may contain the answer to my question. I will now study the paper.

Comment: @Hans for general consideration on bridges and other filtration expansion you can check the last chapter of Protter's book on stochastic differential equations which covers the subject with great generality for semi martingales, there is also a LNM written by Yor and Mansuy on this subject. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: Does LNM stand for Lecture Notes in Mathematics? Is Marc Yor, Roger Mansuy, Aspects of Brownian Motion what you are referring to? And http://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Integration-Differential-Equations-Probability/dp/3642055605/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8?

Comment: @Hans : you right that's the one.